# Elseif o else? problema al cerrar la session.

Tags: php, session

Tengo un sistema de usuarios logueados, cuando salen de la session (logout.php) no desaparece el div de Mi cuenta del usuario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que si hace logout, se muestren los botones de inicio de sesión y registro. He probado con un elseif para indicar que si no existe la session haga esto:

elseif(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ ?>

Login

Pero el problema es que se queda en el codigo del primer if,en el cual se muestra el div con el menú de usuario, y siempre lo muestra esté o no esté logueado. Alguien sabe que pasa?

CODIGO COMPLETO;

introducir el código aquí

```
<?php if($status = 'Active' or $status = 'Canceled') { ?>

        <nav style="width:15%;left:85%;top:-10px;" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php $row['nombre']; ?> &nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Suscripción</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../login/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Salir</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    </li> 
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </ul>
            </div>
           </nav>

    <?php    } 

     elseif(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ ?>

             <button style="float:left;margin:3px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp; Login</button>
              <button style="margin:3px;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; Suscribirse</button>

   <?php } 

     else { ?>

              <button style="float:left;margin:3px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp; Login</button>
              <button style="margin:3px;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; Suscribirse</button>
          <?php  }
                     ?>
```

Comment: `if($status = 'Active' or $status = 'Canceled')` no es lo mismo que `if($status == 'Active' or $status == 'Canceled')` el segundo es lo que tu estás buscando

Answer (score 0):

Validas `$status` pero no la sesión a menos que estatus no cumpla tu condición y por lo que veo el `elseif` y el `else` hacen lo mismo por lo que no tiene sentido hacer el `elseif` y no veo `mi Cuenta` en el html.

Como te comentaron hace un momento es probable que estatus siempre sea `Active` o `Canceled` pero es posible que no exista la sesion.

```
<?php if(($status = 'Active' or $status = 'Canceled') && isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])) : ?>

        <nav style="width:15%;left:85%;top:-10px;" class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                    </div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">  
                    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php $row['nombre']; ?> &nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Suscripción</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../login/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Salir</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    </li> 
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </ul>
            </div>
           </nav>
<?php else: ?>

      <button style="float:left;margin:3px;" type="button" class="btn btn-success navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>&nbsp; Login</button>
      <button style="margin:3px;" type="button" class="btn btn-warning navbar-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp; Suscribirse</button>

<?php   endif; ?>
```

Comment: Exacto era eso!  faltaba añadir && isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"]) eres un crack. Gracias por la ayuda